# Where does the file <project>.git come from?

Tags: git, git-clone

I've initialized several local git repos but none of them have a `<project>.git` file; only a `.git` directory. I would like to clone one of these repos to another machine on the local network, but `clone` seems to require a `<project>.git` file. How does this file get generated?

Comment: What do you mean, "`clone` seems to require a `<project>.git` file"? Are you attempting to do a clone and getting an error message?

Comment: The words in `<>` (triangle brackets) usually refer to some unavoidable parameter or result. In this case when you initialize bare repository you will get something like `<project>.git` **folder**, where `project` is just a name of your project, it might be any word, words, ...

Comment: I neglected to mention that what I actually want to do is set up a clone on a network (NFS) share and sync the two repositories. Maybe I should just use `rsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a `project.git` (and not a `project/.git`), you would need to use `git clone --bare` or `git init --bare`.

That would create a **[bare repository](http://gitrecipes.de/article/show/bare-vs-nonbare)**, one with only the .git content and no working tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to copy the project to some other machine with all the files and `git` data in it then just copy the folder you have with `.git` repository. `.git` directory contains git's metadata (and all version history). This will have the complete working tree of your project with git version history. This is called non bare repository.

A non-bare repository is a clone of another repository, plus local state, such as .git/HEAD, which indicates which revision is checked out, the index, which is used to identify what has changed in the checked out tree and to help prepare commit objects, etc.

A bare repo is `project.git` which doesn't include the working tree and just the `.git` folder. A bare repository created with `git init --bare` or `git clone --bare` is for sharing basically. If you are collaborating with a team of developers, and need a place to share changes to a repo, then you will may create a bare repository in centralized place where all users can push their changes.

So if you need a `bare` repo i.e., `project.git` you will need to create one. The `project.git` or `.git` folder inside the directory is same which contains the `git` metadata and version history.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you're trying to host a git server

[git documentation to setup git server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)

Comment: The thought had crossed my mind. But I think it's overkill for my immediate purposes.